# Mapping specific States and Provinces in R

Tags: r, plot, maps, border

I'm trying to use R to generate a figure with sample localities for my FieldBio project. So far, I've been able to map the US states I want, to map Canada (national border), to overlay these two maps; what I'd like to do, though, is to map the following states/provinces specifically, excluding the others:
California
Nevada
Utah
Colorado
Wyoming
Montana
Idaho
Washington
Oregon
British Columbia
Alberta

Here is the code I've been using so far:

```
>map('state', region = c('california', 'nevada', 'utah', 'colorado', 'wyoming', 'montana', 'idaho', 'oregon', 'washington'), xlim=c(-130,-90), ylim=c(30,60), fill=TRUE, col="gray95")

>map("worldHires","Canada", xlim=c(-130,-90), ylim=c(30,60), col="gray95", fill=TRUE, add=TRUE)
```

This produces a map with the desired states, but canada as a country (cut off at the delimitors I set).

Is there a way to do only the provinces I want? I think I know how to plot the points (I have them as a .csv with lat and long data) on top of this afterward.

I realize that ([R: creating a map of selected Canadian provinces and U.S. states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763421/r-creating-a-map-of-selected-canadian-provinces-and-u-s-states)) is pretty similar, but I'm getting a little lost in the code for that particular example, and I don't need to highlight anything specific.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
library(raster)
states    <- c('California', 'Nevada', 'Utah', 'Colorado', 'Wyoming', 'Montana', 'Idaho', 'Oregon', 'Washington')
provinces <- c("British Columbia", "Alberta")

us <- getData("GADM",country="USA",level=1)
canada <- getData("GADM",country="CAN",level=1)

us.states <- us[us$NAME_1 %in% states,]
ca.provinces <- canada[canada$NAME_1 %in% provinces,]

us.bbox <- bbox(us.states)
ca.bbox <- bbox(ca.provinces)
xlim <- c(min(us.bbox[1,1],ca.bbox[1,1]),max(us.bbox[1,2],ca.bbox[1,2]))
ylim <- c(min(us.bbox[2,1],ca.bbox[2,1]),max(us.bbox[2,2],ca.bbox[2,2]))
plot(us.states, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
plot(ca.provinces, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, add=T)
```

So this uses the `getData(...)` function in package `raster` to grab the SpatialPolygonDataFrames for US states and Canadian provinces from the GADM site. Then it extracts only the states you want (notice that the relevant attribute table field is `NAME_1` and the the states/provinces need to be capitalized properly). Then we calculate the x and y-limits from the bounding boxes of the two (subsetted) maps. Finally we render the maps. Note the use of `add=T` in the second call to `plot(...)`.

And here's a `ggplot` solution.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(us.states,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group))+
  geom_path()+
  geom_path(data=ca.provinces)+
  coord_map()
```

[image]

The advantage here is that `ggplot` manages the layers for you, so you don't have to explicitly calculate `xlim` and `ylim`. Also, IMO there is much more flexibility in adding additional layers. The disadvantage is that, with high resolution maps such as these (esp the west coast of Canada), it is *much* slower.

Comment: Exactly like that! You're a genius! For future reference, how should I go about finding code example like this? I've never taken classes on either R or GIS, so I'm a little in the dark...

Comment: Coming at this from a GIS background, I'm not sure I can help with that. Try searching for "maps in R" and see which hits are most helpful.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for your help! Just knowing the formula for this one problem will help me in the future.

Comment: @jlhoward when i try to ggplot it i get this error: Regions defined for each Polygons
Regions defined for each Polygons
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'long' not found

Comment: `bbox()` doesn't appear to be in the raster package any longer.