# How do I create a map showing temperature across a lake?

Tags: r, maps

I hope this is the right platform to ask this question...

I am trying to create my first map in R and I don't know where/how to start. Basically I want a map of the province Ontario, showing temperature across a specific lake. I have the long/lat and temperature info across my lake of interest but how do I get started with the map? How do I get isolate Ontario from the Canada map?

I downloaded maps and mapdata but I can't seem to isolate provinces.

Any help or links to tutorial is appreciated... thank you

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10763421/3358272